# Scraping multiple webpages in R returns status 127

Tags: javascript, html, r, phantomjs, rvest

I'm relatively new to coding, so this might be a fairly simple solution, but I'm lost.

**WHAT I'M DOING:**
I am trying to scrape data from 93 webpages and format it into a data frame. Each page differs only by the last 9 digits and I've created a vector called "EIN" that contains all of these digits as strings and I'm using a for loop to paste the URL together for each digit (that part works fine).

**THE PROBLEM:**
Each page is JS rendered (so when I try to simply use "rvest" it would always return "NA" for the values). I was informed I could use phantomJS to work around this problem, however, now I get an error message saying, 
*"Error: 'scrape.html' does not exist in current working directory ('C:/Users/Kyle/Documents').
In addition: Warning message:
running command 'phantomjs scrape.js > scrape.html' had status 127"*

If you have any suggestions...I'd really appreciate it.
I've included a sample code with just 3 of the EIN's to illustrate the problem.

THANKS!

**THE CODE:**

```
library(readr)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(rvest)
library(xml2)

Mission <- "text"
Year <- "text"
building_df <- data.frame(Mission, Year)
EIN <- c("20-5110222", "52-2351881", "47-5346354")
id_key <- ""

for (i in 1:3){
   id_key <- EIN[i]
   url <- paste("https://www.guidestar.org/profile/", id_key, sep = "")
   writeLines(sprintf("var page = require('webpage').create();
   page.open('%s', function () {
                    console.log(page.content); //page source
                    phantom.exit();
                    });", url), con="scrape.js")

   system("phantomjs scrape.js > scrape.html")

   webpage <- read_html("scrape.html")
   profile_data <- html_nodes(webpage, ".report-section-text")
   profile_data <- html_text(profile_data)
   Mission <- profile_data[1]
   Year <- profile_data[2]
   profile_df <- data.frame(Mission, Year)
   building_df <- rbind(building_df, profile_df)
}
```

Comment: Maybe I get your code wrong, so a short question: Where do you create the file "scrape.html"? For me it looke like you output the content to the console, but you don't save a .html file. Additional notes: Is phantomJS in your search path / working directory? is this also true for scrape.js? Furthermore maybe have a look at pipes `%>%`as you already use the tidyverse libraries. And the "profile_df" is better built by `c(Mission, Year)`. Also building_df looks a bit strange, but let's first do the scraping.

Comment: Hey thanks for the response! So I discovered a couple problems with what I was trying to do. 1) The file was not being saved in the working directory (so I fixed that). 2) The second problem was a problem with the actual site connection. 

So I've actually decided to write the data scraping algorithm in Python and then do the data analysis in R. That said, I'm using a different website and have a new algorithm, but now the problem seems to be that it's only returning the last page on the list rather than each one. So I'm trying to figure that out now.

Thank you for responding though!

Comment: Feel free to ask a new question or edit this one if you'd loke toget some help with your new approach